# Creating new object instance with arguments array

Tags: php, class, instance

I am trying to create a new instance of a class like this:

```
$obj = new $class;
```

I am doing this in a way that a common set of functions will do this for a number of classes, but now I am implementing some arguments. Now although the handler function could look like this:

```
function newInst($argA = null, $argB = null, $argC = null)
```

This would have to have all the arguments included beforehand and would have an upper limit. So, I am trying to do something like this:

```
function newInst() {
    $obj = new $class(func_get_args());
    ...
}
```

but instead of just the first argument being applied, I would like it to apply the array as a set of arguments. I have tried

```
function newInst() {
    $obj = new $class;
    call_user_func_array(array($obj, '__construct'), func_get_args());
    ...
}
```

but that calls the `__construct` function twice. So, is there any way to use the arguments of a called function to create a new instance that would go through the `__construct` or `classname` function during instantiation?

Comment: `new $class;` OR `new Class;`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That'll work for a *known* number of arguments; I think the problem here is that the arguments are not known.

Comment: @Bracketworks that is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using reflection: [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

```
function createInstance($class, array $arguments) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
    return $reflection->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
}
```

Reflection offers alot, and despite the common claim that it's "*slow*", it's very inoften that reflection will be a true bottleneck in your application; any possibility can be mitigated with caching anyhow.

---

Based on discussion, I'm just amending a hypothetical solution with `count()` checks and naive caching; it would still (*definitely*) need profiling.

```
function createInstance($class, array $arguments) {
    static $cache = [];
    switch (count($arguments)) {
        case 0: return new $class();
        case 1: return new $class($arguments[0]);
        case 2: return new $class($arguments[0], $arguments[1]);
        case 3: return new $class($arguments[0], $arguments[1], $arguments[2]);
    }
    if (!isset($cache[$class])) {
        $cache[$class] = new ReflectionClass($class);
    }
    return $cache[$class]->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
}
```

Comment: Well, its definitely slower, but as it's only used once in a while, its not that bad

Comment: @cgoddard Precisely; if it's an integral component used thousands of times over, then perhaps it's not the fastest solution, but then again, if that's the case then it might be a sign you're doing something you shouldn't ;)

Comment: Righto, I have implemented that function, but I have included a method to check the number of args passed, if none, the it just uses `new $class`, if 1 argument then `new $class(func_get_arg(0))`, if 2 arguments then `new $class(func_get_arg(0), func_get_arg(1))`, then after that it falls back the the `ReflectionClass`. Saves a lot of processing time